Dialog no guarda los datos editados
tengo un dialog que se abre p:commandLink para que se pueda editar un campo de un objeto, bueno cuando edito el valor del campo y le doy al boton de guardar, ese valor se pierde en flow y el back recoge el valor anterior sin modificar, es decir si hay un 2023 y lo modifico a 2001 en el back recoge 2023 en vez de 2001.
Adjunto el trozo de código:


<p:commandLink id="editarNombreHito_#{hitos.indexOf(_hito)}" process="@this" alt="#{msg['editar']}" title="#{msg['editar']}" onclick="PF('cargando').show();" update="editarNombreHitoDialog_#{hitos.indexOf(_hito)}" oncomplete="PF('cargando').hide(); PF('editarNombreHitoDialog_#{hitos.indexOf(_hito)}').show();"
  style="margin-left:2px; margin-right: 11%;">
  <h:graphicImage value="../core/static/images/editar.png" style="width: 21px; height: 23px;" />
</p:commandLink>





<!-- DIALOG PARA EDITAR NOMBRE HITO -->
<p:dialog widgetVar="editarNombreHitoDialog_#{hitos.indexOf(_hito)}" hideEffect="fade" closable="true" maximizable="false" minimizable="false" resizable="false" message="Editar nombre Hito" header="Editar nombre Hito #{hitos.indexOf(_hito)+1}" style="width:100%;"
  id="editarNombreHitoDialog_#{hitos.indexOf(_hito)}" modal="false">

  <h:panelGrid columnClasses="porcen50,porcen50" columns="2" width="100%" style="padding: 3%;" id="editarNombreHitoPanel_#{hitos.indexOf(_hito)}">
    <!-- NOMBRE HITO -->
    <h:column>
      <h:outputLabel value="Nombre hito" style="width:100%; text-align:left;" styleClass="label">
        <span style="color: red">(*)</span>
      </h:outputLabel>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
      <p:inputText id="idNombreHito" value="#{_hito.nombre}" style="width:90%; margin-left: 2%;" maxlength="100">
      </p:inputText>
    </h:column>
  </h:panelGrid>
  <div style="width: 100%; bottom: 10px; background-color: white; height: 8%; border-radius: 4px; right: 3%; padding-top: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: flex; justify-content: center !important;">
    <p:commandButton id="guardarNombreHitoButton_#{hitos.indexOf(_hito)}" value="Guardar" styleClass="boton_dialog_cerrar" action="guardarNombreHito" onclick="PF('cargando').show();" oncomplete="PF('cargando').hide();" update="labelNombreHito_#{hitos.indexOf(_hito)}">
      <f:param name="idHitoEditarNombre" value="#{_hito.id}" />
      <f:param name="nombreHito" value="#{_hito.nombre}" />
    </p:commandButton>
  </div>
</p:dialog>



El flow:
<transition on="guardarNombreHito">
    <set name="flowScope.idHitoEditarNombre" value="requestParameters.idHitoEditarNombre"></set>
    <set name="flowScope.nombreHito" value="requestParameters.nombreHito"></set>
    <evaluate expression="analisisHitosIntermediosController.guardarNombreHito(flowScope.nombreHito, flowScope.idHitoEditarNombre)"/>
</transition>

Y el metodo java del back:
public void guardarNombreHito(String nombreHito, String idHito) {
    Hito hito = new Hito();
    try {
        if((nombreHito != null && !nombreHito.equals("")) && (idHito != null && !idHito.equals(""))) {
            hito = hitoService.getById(idHito);
            hito.setNombre(nombreHito);
            hito.setFechaModificacion(new Date());
            hito.setUsuarioModificacion(Utilies.getUsernameLogueado());
            hitoService.update(hito);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Nombre del hito guardado correctamente"));
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", "Error al guardar el nombre del hito"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error guardarNombreHito. Motivo: " + e, e);
    }
}

No sabria que puede estar pasando. Gracias de antemano.
